# Convert 0s and 1s from text file to a 2-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files

I am given a text file that only has 0 and 1 values. One example is:

```
010
111
010
```

I need to take these values and turn them into a 2-D array. So for the example, I should get an array like this:

```
[[0,1,0] , [1,1,1], [0,1,0]]
```

Each text file has a different number of column and width, so my program should be able to take care of different input matrix sizes. I have tried the following:

```
numpy.loadtxt("file1.txt")
```

However, this gives me the following output array:

```
[  10.  111.   10.]
```

Any guidance would be great!

Comment: What you have written as your desired output is a python *list*. You want numpy arrays, though, right?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `numpy.readtext`. Just use the built-in file handlers:

```
import numpy as np
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    arr = np.array([list(map(int, line.strip())) for line in f])
print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: @robertang - Perhaps you would like to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.genfromtxt` to get fixed width columns.  the `delimiter` parameter specifies the width of each column.  I use `dtype=np.int8` to use the smallest footprint since OP said values will only be zero or one.

```
import numpy as np

np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', delimiter=[1, 1, 1], dtype=np.int8)

array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: I believe `np.int0` is giving a word-sized `int`. Best use `bool` or `np.int8` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also do it without `map` magic.

```
import numpy as np

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    arr = np.array([[int(bin) for bin in line] for line in f])
print(arr)
```

Comment: While I usually prefer comprehensions over `map` and `filter`, in the case of mapping a built-in, map is faster than comprehensions, and more importantly, it is more readable than nested comprehensions. But the differences are negligible.